# Kotlin breakline in comment not working

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In `Java` I often use `<br/>` (or another html tag) in commend like this to make comment easy to read

```
/**
 * Line 1 <br/>
 * Line 2
 */
```

In Kotlin, I write comment like this but it not working ("Line 2" don't break to new line). Is there any way to achieve it (any Settings or Plugin)?

Comment: does it consider <br/> as a comment too or it is completely ignored ?

Comment: @Umair It's completely ignored. I am using markdown in now for my comment now

Comment: ah yes thank you for pointing this out .. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlin docs doesn't support HTML tag but Markdown syntax. As per it

> When you do want to insert `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.

See more information at https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p and https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html#kdoc-syntax

Comment: Markdown working in comment. I will use it instead of html tag. Thank you so much